# How to implement XXTEA in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, xxtea

Anyone knows how to implement XXTEA in MySQL?

For example - SELECT xxtea_encrypt('text here', 'key here');

possible implementation is by creating a FUNCTION in MySQL using CREATE FUNCTION statement, e.g.

CREATE FUNCTION xxtea_encrypt
  XXTEA Procedures here...
  RETURN encrypted string

Thanks & Best regards

Comment: I have been told that you can use UDF to compile function extension for MySql using C. Anyone has any success extending Mysql functions via this method? and what are the pitfalls or things to look out for?

Comment: Just want to say that recreating xxtea encrypt and decrypt using CREATE FUNCTION statement in MySQL is possible. I couldn't post the scripts here yet, but just want to let those who are wondering if it can be done without the UDF method, the answer is "Yes!"

I will try to get clearance from company to see if I can post the script here for sharing..